# Overridden method does not throw

Tags: java, исключения

```
public interface EmployeeDAO {
public static final String SQL_FIND_ALL ="SELECT * FROM employees";

public List<Employee> findAll();
}

public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {
private Connection conn;

public EmployeeDAOImpl() throws Exception {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(new FileInputStream("demo.properties"));

    String user = props.getProperty("user");
    String password = props.getProperty("password");
    String dburl = props.getProperty("dburl");

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, user, password);

    System.out.println("DB connection successful to: " + dburl);
}



public List<Employee> findAll() throws Exception    {
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery ...
}
```

И для метода findAll() получаю следующие: overridden method does not throw java.lang.Exception

Comment: удалите, у метода findAll() - throws Exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну я не вижу концовки этого метода, но смею предположить что все операции, возвращающие исключения обернуты в этот **try/catch.** Поэтому ставить **throw** в определении метода не надо.

Если в интерфейсе или классе, который вы переопределяете, нет проброса исключения, то в подклассе их добавлять нельзя.

Comment: Концовка метода
           catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        finally {
            //close(stmt, rs);
            stmt.close();
            rs.close();
        }
        return list;
Убрал throws Exception, но теперь ругается на блок finally

Comment: А как сделать проброс исключений?

Comment: Так добавте throw в интерфейс

Comment: @A.Grin потому что оба вызова метода `close` нужно обернуть в отдельный try-catch. И делать `throws Exception` - вообще моветон. Если в методе возможны какие-то исключения, которые он не может обработать сам, то должен быть объявлен проброс только этих исключений, а не безличного `Exception`.